# SSH through OpenVPN on iPad

Tags: ipad, ssh, vpn

I have an iPad Air M1 and I am trying to SSH into a server at my university, which requires us to either be connected via Ethernet cable in a uni building or pass through a VPN (we use OpenVPN). a-shell’s SSH works fine when I am connected via cable, but when I connect e.g. to wifi, enable the VPN and try to SSH (same command I use normally!) using a-Shell I get the following logs:

```
[~/Documents]$ ssh -v USER@IP
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB8DE-43C9-4356-AB13-8276E989C815/Documents/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to IP:22 as 'USER'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

And it just hangs there forever. Same if I use Termius, although I can’t see logs there.

Pinging the IP does not work if the VPN is not connected but works if it is, so the VPN is correctly connected. Also the cluster has a web interface (IBM LICO) and I can connect it only when I am using the VPN, as expected.